# Dos batch: How to get filename from variable that isn't an argument?

Tags: parsing, batch-file

I see lots of examples to use %nx1 to get just the filename of a file passed in with %1.

But what if you have another variable set with a filepath and want to programmatically get the filename from that

For example

```
@echo off
SET MYPATH="c:\program files\myapp\somefile.ext"
SET MYPATHFILE = ??
```

I am trying to get just "somefile.ext". 
I tried replacing 1 with the var name

```
%nxMYPATH
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following line:

```
FOR /F %%I IN ("%MYPATH%") DO SET MYPATHFILE=%%~nxI
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! It's so obvious now... just couldn't see it

Comment: That this could ever have been obvious to anyone... says a lot about the mess we're in.